# Is this image showing white Americans to be less racist than the other major racial groups from a valid source?

Tags: united-states, race

I've seen these statistics several times, shared over social media.

[image]

- Is this based on real statistics from a legitimate source(and what is the original source)?

I did reverse google image searches, but I found the image mostly on social media posts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112261/discussion-on-question-by-vsz-is-this-image-showing-white-americans-to-be-less-r). Please do not comment further here.

Comment: Please take further comments to chat.